# Magneto 2 extension using view/frontend/layout to place block in header.container not working

Tags: magento2, extensions, xml

Hi I create a custom module that lets people who are logged in and have an attribute shows a button.  I would like to do it all from the extension without touching the default.xml.  I would like to reference the container and place a block inside of it but it does not seem to be working.
Here is the block:

```php
<?php

namespace WorldSynergy\LoginPortal\Block;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Url;
use Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection;
{

class Portal extends Template
{
    protected $_customerUrl;
    protected $_customer;
    protected $httpContext;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context  $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection $customer,
        Url $customerUrl,
        Context $httpContext,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customer = $customer;
        $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        if $this->$_customer->create()->addAttributeToSelect('is_allowed',array('eq'=>1)) {
            return $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
        }
    }
}
```

here is the layout file located at vendor/namespace/view/frontend/layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <block as="portal" class="vendor\namespace\Block\Portal" name="portal" template="vendor_namespce::portal.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

here is the custom .phtml file just saying hello now.

```php
<?php
/**

 */
?>
<div>
    <?=// $block->isLoggedIn() ?>
    hello
</div>
```

for some reason it is not placing it in the container and was wondering if some could point me to the right place.

here is the defualt.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
    <body>
        <!-- Inline scripts -->
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Magento\Translation\Block\Js" name="translate" template="Magento_Translation::translate.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie" name="js_cookies" template="Magento_Theme::js/cookie.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Notices" name="global_notices" template="html/notices.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="theme.js" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::jsconfigurator.phtml" />
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="theme_child.js" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::jsconfigurator_child.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <!-- Inline scripts END -->

        <!-- Header. RD-Navbar -->
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <container name="rd.navbar-wrap" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rd-navbar">
                <container name="rd.navbar" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rd-navbar-panel layout_1" />
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceBlock name="skip_to_content" remove="true" />
        <!-- Header. RD-Navbar END -->

        <!-- Navbar Collapse -->
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="navbar.collapse" template="Magento_Theme::rd-navbar-collapse.phtml"/>
        <move element="navbar.collapse" destination="rd.navbar.collapse" before="-" />
        <!-- Navbar Collapse End -->

        <!-- Header Panel -->
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" htmlClass="panel page-header__panel">
            <container name="header.panel.grid-container" htmlClass="container" htmlTag="div" before="-">
                <container name="header.switchers" htmlClass="header-switchers" htmlTag="div" before="-"/>
                <container name="panel.container.wrap" htmlClass="panel-container-wrap" htmlTag="div"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <!-- Header Panel END -->

        <!-- Header Content -->
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" htmlClass="page-header__content">
            <container name="header-wrapper.grid-container" htmlClass="container" htmlTag="div" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <!-- Header Content END -->

        <!-- Navbar Collapse -->
        <container name="rd.navbar.collapse" htmlClass="rd-navbar-collapse-container" htmlTag="div" after="-">
            <container name="rd.navbar.collapse.items" htmlClass="rd-navbar-collapse" htmlTag="div">
                <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language_mobile" as="store_language" template="switch/languages_mobile.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="currency_mobile" before="store_language" template="currency_mobile.phtml" after="store_language_mobile"/>
            </container>
        </container>

        <move element="top.links" destination="rd.navbar.collapse.items"/>
        <!-- Navbar Collapse End -->

        <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me where you want to add those things?

Comment: I would like to add it the header.container. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to add your custom phtml file, right?

Comment: Then do the code into custom.phtml file instade of hi.

Comment: It is not showing the hi.  I just put the hello there to test if would work.  Its not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Normally on the block, I usually this on top of my block:

```
namespace vendor\namespace\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface; 

class YOUR_CLASS_NAME extends Template implements BlockInterface {
```

And in your default.xml I didn't find where you call your block like:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="portal" template="Vendor_Namespace::your_file.phtml">
```

And pay attention to capital letters because it makes a difference.

Are you sure you are not missing to add some file?

You can see [this tutorial](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html), it's very helpful.

Comment: Thanks,  I will look into the implements.  I am trying not to override the default.xml because i need this to be an extension i can move to multiple sites.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @WS_Marc I didn't create extensions yet. I just create custom blocks and widgets to custom themes.

Comment: @WS_Marc reading the DevDoc on Magento website they suggest you to use theme inheritance to extend file (not override). https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html#theme-inherit-layout

Comment: @WS_Marc if my tips help you please let me know to edit my answer, then you can check as the right answer.

Comment: @BraDev...Thanks for input but that does not do what I looking for.  All the Best!

Comment: @WS_Marc I tested here creating a default.xml for an extended block just with my block setting the parent and before attribute to add a Feefo Review on the header and worked well mate. Didn't override the main default.xml. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I have not found a solution yet.  Can you show me what you are talking about doing with file structure?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As my theme has the inheritance of Blank Magento Theme I created a `default.xml` on `vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout` and not reset or override everything.

My file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container" htmlClass="custom-header">
            <container name="custom_header_top_content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-header_top-content" before="-">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_header_feefo_reviews" before="-" template="TheTrade_FeefoReviews::widget/service_simple.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="style" xsi:type="string">Service Simple</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Observe that I didn't duplicate the default default.xml. I'm just saying that I want to add and where I want to add this Feefo Review widget. And inside of the correspondent container, I set where I want to add using before/after in the element.

PS.: I know that in my case is a widget, but is a widget inside a block and the inheritance works quite similar.

I hope to help you now.

I used all link that I already share with you and this: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-widget/